# Detecting touches outside a scroll view programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a horizontally scrollable UIScrollView. [I am using this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content). I have the scrollview appearing and working fine, but currently stumped on the "Detecting touches outside a scroll view" part of the tutorial.

The problem is that I am creating everything programmatically. I am especially stumped about this part of the tutorial code  (in **ScrollViewContainer.m**):

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (view == self) {
        return _scrollView;
        }
    return view;
}
```

where `_scrollView` is an IBOutlet (in **ScrollViewContainer.h**):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

As I understand it, the _scrollView "connection" is done on the Storyboard via outlet. How am I supposed to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

with the use of this code i find my touch object and hides the view so hope you can fix it with a bit of trick and modification on same code just pass your scrollview object and log inside that its touched or not.

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Touch Events
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint imgPop = [touch locationInView: _scrollView];
    if ([_scrollView pointInside:imgPop withEvent:event])
    {
        NSLog(@"Touch Inside ScrollView");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Touch Outside ScrollView");
    }
}
```

let me know if you find any difficulty to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the touches outside the `scrollview` you may simply access the `touchEvents` of the `UIView`.

- touchesBegan,
- touchesEnded,
- touchesMoved,
- touchesCancelled

Try touches began for any single tap you want.

Answer (score 0):

That custom `hitTest:withEvent:` method in Ray Wenderlich tutorial is only needed if you've made the scroll view smaller that the screen (and set its `clipsToBounds` to `NO`):

[image: app screenshot]

The method will make touches happening outside the scroll view be forwarded to it.

So in your source code you need to call something like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
...
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
    20, 
    20, 
    self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 
    self.view.frame.size.height - 20
)];
```